# IOException in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httprequest, ioexception

I'm trying to do a simple Http Request using AsyncTask, here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {


    String url = "http://www.mysamplecode.com/DowloadData";
    new MyAsyncTask(this).execute(url);

  }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private static final int REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT = 3 * 1000;
    private static final int WAIT_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000;
    private final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    final HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams();
    HttpResponse response;
    private String content =  null;
    private boolean error = false;

    private Context mContext;
    private int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private Notification mNotification;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    public MyAsyncTask(Context context){



        this.mContext = context;

        //Get the notification manager
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        createNotification("Data download is in progress","");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String URL = null;
        String param1 = "abc";
        String param2 = "xyz";

        try {

            //URL passed to the AsyncTask
            URL = urls[0];
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);
            ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);


            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

            //Any other parameters you would like to set
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1",param1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2",param2));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            //Response from the Http Request
            response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            //Check the Http Request for success
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                content = out.toString();
            }
            else{
                //Closes the connection.
                Log.w("HTTP1:",statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.w("HTTP2:",e );
            content = e.getMessage();
            error = true;
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("HTTP3:",e );
            content = e.getMessage();
            error = true;
            cancel(true);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("HTTP4:",e );
            content = e.getMessage();
            error = true;
            cancel(true);
        }

        return content;
    }

  protected void onCancelled() {
        createNotification("Error occured during data download", content);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
        if (error) {
            createNotification("Data download ended abnormally!",content);
        } else {
            createNotification("Data download is complete!","");
        }
    }

    private void createNotification(String contentTitle, String contentText) {

        //Build the notification using Notification.Builder
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
        .setContentText(contentText);

        //Get current notification
        mNotification = builder.getNotification();

        //Show the notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
    }

}
}
```

it seems to work, but MyAsyncTask always gives an IOException and the method onCancelled() is called, closing the request with an error message, why? how can i solve this problem?
Log (attached to the parameter "content" when i catch an exception) shows the message "Method not allowed", there's something wrong in the code?

Comment: I think it is a restriction, you specify permissions `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in AndroidManifest.xml ? or your server is not available

Comment: seems like a server side issue ...

Comment: Yes i do, so it could be a server problem? Code is ok?

Comment: I know `out.close()` shouldn't have any effect, but try moving the `close()` to after the `toString()`

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't work...maybe i've to try to connect with another server

Comment: It was a server problem, now code works. So, can i use it also in order to take a json string after an http request?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe its a bit late but changing your URL from "http://www.mysamplecode.com/DowloadData"  to "https://www.mysamplecode.com/DowloadData" could handle it.

Comment: This answer, suggesting the use of HTTPS instead of HTTP would've been better served in a comment.